# Using class or static method as default_factory in dataclasses

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I want to populate an attribute of a dataclass using the `default_factory` method. However, since the factory method is only meaningful in the context of this specific class, I want to keep it *inside* the class (e.g. as a static or class method). For example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List

@dataclass
class Deck:
    cards: List[str] = field(default_factory=self.create_cards)

    @staticmethod
    def create_cards():
        return ['King', 'Queen']
```

However, I get this error (as expected) on line 6:

> NameError: name 'self' is not defined

How can I overcome this issue? I don't want to move the `create_cards()` method out of the class.

Comment: where is `self` in code? and on which line error is coming.

Comment: @ParthS007 Thank you, I fixed the code (I had omitted the `self`). The error comes from line 6.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NameError within class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57644907/nameerror-within-class-definition)

Comment: @KurtBourbaki did I answer your question?

Comment: @momo Your answer helped me solving the issue, yes. I'll add a comment below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possible solution is to move it to `__post_init__(self)`. For example:

```
@dataclass
class Deck:
    cards: List[str] = field(default_factory=list)

    def __post_init__(self):
        if not self.cards:
            self.cards = self.create_cards()

    def create_cards(self):
        return ['King', 'Queen']
```

Output:

```
d1 = Deck()
print(d1) # prints Deck(cards=['King', 'Queen'])
d2 = Deck(["Captain"])
print(d2) # prints Deck(cards=['Captain'])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not very convinced about the `__post_init__` method though: it seems to me like a sort of workaround that makes the `default_factory` parameter less intuitive to use (since it's basically overriding it). Why don't we completely omit the `field(...)` part then?

Comment: The reason for using `field(...)` is to provide a default value. If we omit this part, `d1 = Deck()` is no longer valid and must be called with an empty list, i.e. `d1 = Deck([])` (which is IHMO less elegant). With the suggested approach, your code becomes very flexible (e.g. you might allow different types `cards: Union[List[str], str]`) and can always correctly initialize it to a list `self.cards = [self.cards]`). This might also be useful if you develop a library for other developers because you know, that your method will always behave the same way and allows crappy input (`Deck(None)`)

Answer (score 4):

One option is to wait until *after* you define the `field` object to make `create_cards` a static method. Make it a regular function, use it as such to define the `cards` field, *then* replace it with a static method that wraps the function.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List

@dataclass
class Deck:

    # Define a regular function first (we'll replace it later,
    # so it's not going to be an instance method)
    def create_cards():
        return ['King', 'Queen']

    # Use create_cards as a regular function
    cards: List[str] = field(default_factory=create_cards)

    # *Now* make it it a static method
    create_cards = staticmethod(create_cards)
```

This works because the `field` object is created while the class is being defined, so it doesn't need to be a static method yet.

Comment: did not know that `staticmethod` is also a function

Comment: `staticmethod` is a type whose instances *wrap* functions; it's the descriptor protocol that causes both `Deck.create_cards` and `Deck().create_cards` to evaluate to the underlying function.

Comment: (Fixed a typo; `create_cards`, not `cards`, should have been the argument to `staticmethod`.)

Answer (score 2):

Can you do something like this?

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Deck:
    cards: list[str] = field(
             default_factory=lambda: ["King", "Queen"])
```

ps. in python 3.9+ you can use `list` instead of `typing.List`.

Answer (score 1):

I adapted momo's answer to be self contained in a class and without thread-safety (since I was using this in asyncio.PriorityQueue context):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Any, ClassVar

@dataclass(order=True)
class FifoPriorityQueueItem:
    data: Any=field(default=None, compare=False)
    priority: int=10
    sequence: int=field(default_factory=lambda: {0})
    counter: ClassVar[int] = 0

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.sequence = FifoPriorityQueueItem.next_seq()

    @staticmethod
    def next_seq():
        FifoPriorityQueueItem.counter += 1
        return FifoPriorityQueueItem.counter

def main():
    import asyncio
    print('with FifoPriorityQueueItem is FIFO')
    q = asyncio.PriorityQueue()
    q.put_nowait(FifoPriorityQueueItem('z'))
    q.put_nowait(FifoPriorityQueueItem('y'))
    q.put_nowait(FifoPriorityQueueItem('b', priority=1))
    q.put_nowait(FifoPriorityQueueItem('x'))
    q.put_nowait(FifoPriorityQueueItem('a', priority=1))
    while not q.empty():
        print(q.get_nowait().get_data())

    print('without FifoPriorityQueueItem is no longer FIFO')
    q.put_nowait((10, 'z'))
    q.put_nowait((10, 'y'))
    q.put_nowait((1, 'b'))
    q.put_nowait((10, 'x'))
    q.put_nowait((1, 'a'))
    while not q.empty():
        print(q.get_nowait()[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Results in:

```
with FifoPriorityQueueItem is FIFO
b
a
z
y
x
without FifoPriorityQueueItem is no longer FIFO
a
b
x
y
z
```